# Multistage dockerfile: how to install without --user pip3 argument?

Tags: python, docker

I'm new to docker, and I'm not entirely sure why this works.

I tried writing my dockerfile without the `--user` argument supplied to `pip3` to install my `requirements.txt` file, but for some reason, copying the setup outputs from the `${INSTALL}` dir to the `${APP}` dir isn't working for me.

**How can I write this such that I don't need to rely on the `--user` argument supplied to `pip3`?**

Using said argument works for now, but it's just really bugging me that I can't make this do what I want it to do.

I build the image using this command:

```
docker image build --no-cache -t apptest .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine as base
ENV APP="/app"
ENV INSTALL="/install"
ENV LOC="/root/.local"
ENV LOCBIN="${LOC}/bin"
ENV PATH $PATH:${LOC}:${LOCBIN}

FROM base as builder
WORKDIR ${INSTALL}

COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt

#install all dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache curl python3 pkgconfig python3-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev musl-dev make gcc
RUN pip3 install --user --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

FROM base

COPY --from=builder ${LOC} ${LOC}
COPY --from=builder ${LOCBIN} ${LOCBIN}
COPY ./src/ ${APP}
COPY ./src/Cogs/ ${APP}/Cogs
COPY ./src/Documentation/ ${APP}/Documentation
COPY ./src/Models/ ${APP}/Models
COPY ./src/OneNight/ ${APP}/OneNight

WORKDIR ${APP}

#start the service
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "service.py" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you install Python packages, code goes all over the place. E.g. libraries go into site-packages, scripts go into bin/, etc.. So you need to install everything in one place to make it easy to copy. Your options are `--user` or a virtualenv, basically, or copying lots of different directories. See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/
2. That being said, you might not need a multi-stage build. You want one here because you're using a compiler. But you might only need a compiler because you're using Alpine Linux. For normal Linux distributions, most Python packages have binary precompiled wheels on PyPI, so much of the time you don't need a compiler at all.

It's quite possible switching to Debian-based base image (`python:3.8-slim-buster`) might allow you to just install everything without compiler. See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll just keep using --user since it doesn't seem like there's a reasonable way around it.

As for the multi-stage build, I tried it out with using the debian-based image, and the size is 2x as large (162 MB), but at the end of the day, I think that's worth it considering the build time significantly went down.